# Best way to cause re-renders when non-state variables change

Tags: reactjs

I have a separate data model object that I'm passing into UI components as a prop. I need portions of the UI to re-render when certain properties in the model object change. What's the best way of achieving this?

Do I create a dummy counter state and send the setState function into the data model to increment whenever I need the UI to change? This seems clunky and difficult to modularize for mapping certain changed properties to certain portions of the UI that need to be rerendered.

Comment: Best approach by far: put the non-state variables into state

Comment: I would like to do this if possible, but the structure of the data model doesn't really permit it.

Edit: For reference, the data model consists of a rendering engine for WebGL/Canvas based content. It updates extremely frequently and these updates are made independent of React's ecosystem. React is really just a thin layer of UI on top that I want to reflect certain properties within said engine.

Comment: If the updates are too frequent for React to handle well, one approach would be to essentially debounce your state setters (perhaps have only a single state, in context, that's linked to that data)

Comment: Hm, I can definitely see a debounce addressing performance issues, but in order to actually cause a state change I'd still need to somehow trigger one from within the model. Is there a better way of doing so other than just using dummy counters and the like every time I happen to change something in the model?

Comment: @GeorgeLiebert I'm having a similar issue. My react component is just a presenter for a non-react object that changes outside of react. Did you ever solve this?